# Scikit-learn MLPRegressor - How to get results independent from random seed?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

I try to learn some a sine function by using a MLP. Unfortunately, the results drastically depend on the random seed. 
How could I adjust the MLPRegressor, so that the results get less dependent on the random seed?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

LOOK_BACK = 10

x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
y = np.sin(x)

dataX,dataY = [],[]
for i in range(len(y)-LOOK_BACK-1):
        dataX.append(y[i:(i+LOOK_BACK)])
        dataY.append(y[i+LOOK_BACK])
x_train = np.array(dataX)
y_train = np.array(dataY)


for i in range(10):
        print "np.random.seed(%d)"%(i)
        np.random.seed(i)
        model = MLPRegressor(activation='tanh',solver='adam')
        model.fit(x_train,y_train)
        train_predict = model.predict(x_train)
        print 'MSE train:', mean_squared_error(train_predict,y_train)
```

Output:

```
np.random.seed(0)
MSE train: 0.00167560534562
np.random.seed(1)
MSE train: 0.0050531872206
np.random.seed(2)
MSE train: 0.00279393534973
np.random.seed(3)
MSE train: 0.00224293537385
np.random.seed(4)
MSE train: 0.00154350859516
np.random.seed(5)
MSE train: 0.00383997358155
np.random.seed(6)
MSE train: 0.0265389606087
np.random.seed(7)
MSE train: 0.00195637404624
np.random.seed(8)
MSE train: 0.000590823529864
np.random.seed(9)
MSE train: 0.00393172460516
```

The seeds 6,9 and 8 produce different orders of the MSE. How could I prevent this?

Comment: try this: `MLPRegressor(activation='tanh',solver='adam', random_state=0)`

Comment: @MaxU This seems to be the same as setting `np.random.seed(0)`. But still the MLPRegressor depends too much on the random state.

Comment: of course it does - it uses random values for the initialization (of weights). What is your goal? If you want predictable and stable results use `random_state`

Comment: @MaxU My goal is to have a MLP that is independent of most random initialisations. I think that the MSE should more depend on the iterations or other hyper parameters than the random state. Is this wrong?

Comment: you can use `GridSearchCV` for tuning hyperparameters. Beside that it'll return you a mean (average) scores...

Comment: Unfortunately, backpropagation algorithms are susceptible to local minima entrapment and depends on good initialization. There are two way around this: (1) train the same network several times with different initial weights, keep the one that performed the best on test set (2) For smaller networks you can optimize weights using particle swarm optimization. PSO provides a near global optimum solution, is less sensitive to the nature of objective function and is less reliable on good initial solution.

Comment: @Aechlys Thanks for this explanation! The PSO seems to be promising. Is there an easy way to use PSO instead of backpropagation in scikit or keras?

Answer (score 2):

Multi layer perceptron as well as other neural network architectures suffer from the fact that their corresponding loss functions have numerous local optima. Thus all gradient algorithms are heavily dependent on what initialization is chosen. And rather than seeing this as undesirable you can view the initialization (determined through random_state) as an additional hyperparameter that gives you flexibility.

Just for the record, the differences in your MSE are not that big and if your goal is to perfectly overfit then change the regularization parameter alpha to zero (the default value is alpha=0.0001)